# PDF Footer Page Not Update for Multiple Result when SSRS Export

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have SSRS Report which print the Letter. And in letter we use footer part.
Now, From SQL, we used Stored Procedures. And it Generated Multiple Rows. For each Rows, SSRS Report is generated And we export PDF file. Which Generated Combine File for each rows of Stored Procedures.

Example, PDF have 5 Pages.
And Suppose Stored Procedures return 10 Rows; Then PDF have total 55 Pages.

In SP one column we used in Footer Part which have different values for each rows.
And we used that column in SSRS Footer Part.

So, When we export to PDD. Like 5 pages of PDF is generated for 1 row. Then from 6th Page generate 2nd Row Data. And So On.

Issue: In Footer for first 5 Pages, first Row's column data Display.
Then in 6th Page's footer, Again First Row's column data Display.
In Image 1, Page Footer is 12345. And This 12345 came from SP result Row 1.
Same Footer 12345 is showing in page number 6. But for 6th Page value is 99999 which is 2nd row of SP result.

Result I Want: In 6th Pages, 2nd Row's Column data Need to Display(that is 99999). Next In 11th Pages, 3rd Row's column data Display.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UEYQ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgK4N.jpg)

We tried Grouping, Reset Page Number, Footer Property Display Page. But Not Working.